# Object in foreach storing only last value JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I have a specific format that needs to be stored in a database, and I am almost there, just don't know and could not find the solution, how to make foreach to store all objects, not just the last one. This is the original code that returns me only last result:

```
optionDetails.done((data) => {

    _.each(data, function(option, key) {
        column.config.options_product = {
            id: "product_" + key.toString(),
            text: option.identifier
        };

    });
}
```

I know that this can be set like empty array and store values with an array but then the format will be also array and will not be saved in the database.

So how should I approach this, maybe store it in an array then convert to object. The ideal would be concatenation:

```
optionDetails.done((data) => {

    _.each(data, function(option, key) {
        column.config.options_product += {
            id: "product_" + key.toString(),
            text: option.identifier
        };

    });
}
```

This is the format that I need:

```
{id: "product_4", text: "1000003"}
```

But this does not work. If someone knows the right path to go to, please share. Thanks.

Comment: What's the format you want? Can you post a sample of what a correct object would look like?

Comment: I have added the format that I need, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: That just shows one, what should it look like if you have multiple products, as your loop suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store multiple objects like `{id: "product_4", text: "1000003"}` you'll either 
have to (i) wrap them in an array; or (ii) provide a unique key for each and store them in an object:

**Option (i)**

```
column.config.options_product = []

optionDetails.done((data) => {
    _.each(data, function(option, key) {
        column.config.options_product.push({
            id: "product_" + key.toString(),
            text: option.identifier
        });
    });
}
```

Output:

```
[
    {id: "product_1", text: "foo1"},
    {id: "product_2", text: "foo2"},
    // (...)
]
```

**Option (ii)**

```
column.config.options_product = {}

optionDetails.done((data) => {
    _.each(data, function(option, key) {
        column.config.options_product[key] = {
            id: "product_" + key.toString(),
            text: option.identifier
        };
    });
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "0": {id: "product_1", text: "foo1"},
    "1": {id: "product_2", text: "foo2"},
    // (...)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

+= will not concatenate objects. You need to add values to a specific key instead. You need to add objects explicitly. So convert it into an array first and then use the push operator to push the objects.

That is:

```
column.config.options_product = []
 _.each(data, function(option, key) {
        column.config.options_product.push({
            id: "product_" + key.toString(),
            text: option.identifier
        };

    }));
```